# Items disappear when setting a mask upon their container

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I dinamically build a menu: this menu is made up of two nested MovieClips:

- externalContainer_mc;
- itemsContainer_mc (inside externalContainer_mc at 0,0);

itemsContainer loads a dinamic number of MenuItems: they are library objects (extending the MovieClip class). Anything works just fine, but **if**, when anything is loaded, **I put a mask** (`itemsContainer_mc.mask=my_mask`) **upon itemsContainer, every MenuItem disappears AND it isn't even clickable anymore**. What happens?

Comment: What is the content of my_mask? Is it transparent?

Comment: my_mask is a regular movieclip made at author time with a shape (no code here).

Comment: The mask must not be a transparent one.

Comment: Maybe I solved, even if partially... The mask MUST be on stage: I put it offstage to avoid adding too much things on stage.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mask contains some pixel data, otherwise it will hide everything:

```
my_mask.beginFill(0x000000);
my_mask.drawRect(0, 0, your_width, your_height);
my_mask.endFill();
```

Comment: The mask is built at author time with a regular shape (it is hand drawn, no code).

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the mask with code, it is good practice to first set the mask and the maskee to cache as bitmaps.

```
itemsContainer_mc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
my_mask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
itemsContainer_mc.mask = my_mask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own mask and export it using a class name, then use it. this will work.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me! If I create a class, I add it to the DisplayList (addChild) and I set it as a mask, the effect is the same as having it offstage (it "freezes" all the content under it and makes it disappear). It looks like an initialization issue but I can't say much more.

Comment: Maybe I've found: the mask must be a child of the DisplayObject that contains the masked MovieClip. I was somewhat "inspired" by the AIR 2 little paragraph here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0b.html (I couldn't find anything more specific but it worked).